# Map not zoomed in anymore when changing screen orientation

Tags: android, maps

When I zoom into the map on my android application, and then I switch my orientation from portrait to landscape, the map zooms out and doesn't retain its zoomed in state. I would like for it to stay zoomed in even though I switched to landscape mode. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

via @miguel

`bundle.putDouble("lat", mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude);
 bundle.putDouble("lon", mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
 bundle.putFloat("zoom", mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);`

Then on onCreate, restore the map state like this:

`bundle.getDouble("lat");
 bundle.getDouble("lon");
 bundle.getDouble("zoom");`

Answer (score 0):

I think adding this to the manifest will fix it.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Or You would save the camera position which will also handle the user moved the map at the same time.  The orientation dimensions change hopefully is handled by Google.

```
private CameraPosition currentCameraPosition;
private static final String SAVED_INSTANCE_CAMERA_POSITION = "com.gosylvester.bestrides.cameraPosition";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // save the current camera position;
    if (currentCameraPosition != null) {
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(SAVED_INSTANCE_CAMERA_POSITION,
                currentCameraPosition);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mMap != null) {
        currentCameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // First Run checks
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        currentCameraPosition = null;
    } else {
        // get the saved_Instance state
        // always get the default when key doesn't exist
        currentCameraPosition = savedInstanceState
                .containsKey(SAVED_INSTANCE_CAMERA_POSITION) ? (CameraPosition) savedInstanceState
                .getParcelable(SAVED_INSTANCE_CAMERA_POSITION) : null;
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map).getView();
    if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    // We use the new method when supported
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    // We check which build version we are using.
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                        // if there is a cameraPosition then move to it.
                        if (currentCameraPosition != null) {
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newCameraPosition(currentCameraPosition));
                        }
                    } 
                });
     }
}
```